# Generate sequence in alphanumeric in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sequence

I am working a SQL Server stored procedure to generate a 10 digits sequence with the following patterns where `[CustomerCode]` is say 'ABC':

```
[CustomerCode]0000001
...
[CustomerCode]9999999
[CustomerCode]A000001
...
[CustomerCode]Z999999
[CustomerCode]ZA00001
...
[CustomerCode]ZZ99999
[CustomerCode]ZZA0001
...
[CustomerCode]ZZZZZZZ
```

So this stored procedure will take a string as input parameter, and return the next value e.g it takes 'ABCZ999999' and returns 'ABCZA00001'.

I have the following stored procedure and functions but they do not work fully and I can't seem to get it right.

Any help is appreciated.

```
-- Function to increment numeric value
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IncrementNumericValue] 
    (@CurrentValue Varchar(2))  
RETURNS Varchar(2)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @RetValue Varchar(2)

    IF (@CurrentValue < CAST(9 AS Varchar(2)))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST((CAST(@CurrentValue AS Int) + Cast(1 AS Int)) AS Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE IF (@CurrentValue >= CAST(9 AS Varchar(2)))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST(0 AS Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST('-' AS Varchar(2))
    END
    
    RETURN (@RetValue)
END

-- Function to increment alpha value
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IncrementAlphaValue] 
    (@CurrentValue Varchar(2))  
RETURNS Varchar(2)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @RetValue Varchar(2)

    IF (@CurrentValue < CAST(9 AS Varchar(2)))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST((CAST(@CurrentValue AS Int) + CAST(1 AS Int)) AS Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE IF (@CurrentValue = CAST(9 AS Varchar(2)))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST('A' As Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE IF ((@CurrentValue >= CAST('A' AS Varchar(2))) 
             AND (@CurrentValue < CAST('Z' AS Varchar(2))))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST((Char((CAST(ASCII(@CurrentValue) AS Int) + CAST(1 AS Int)))) AS Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE IF (@CurrentValue = CAST('Z' AS Varchar(2)))
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST(0 AS Varchar(2))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @RetValue = CAST('-' AS Varchar(2))
    END
    
    RETURN (@RetValue)
END

-- Function to calculate the next sequence of the pattern
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextSequence]
    @NewTarget Varchar(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastVariable Varchar(10) 
    DECLARE @PositionIndex Int
    DECLARE @PassParameterWidth Int
    DECLARE @TargetWidth Int
    DECLARE @SelectedValue Varchar(2)
    DECLARE @NewValue Varchar(2)
    DECLARE @FinalValue Varchar(10)
    DECLARE @ReplaceStringLength Int
    DECLARE @ReplaceString Varchar(10)
    DECLARE @NewCODE Varchar(10)
    DECLARE @MaxTargetWidth Int
    DECLARE @customerCode char(3)
    DECLARE @NumberOfNine Int
    DECLARE @AlphaNumericPartWidth Int

    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            -- Input
            SET @customerCode = 'ABC'
            SELECT  @LastVariable = 'ABCZ999999'

            SET @PassParameterWidth = Len(@LastVariable)
            SET @AlphaNumericPartWidth = @PassParameterWidth - Len(@customerCode)
            SET @LastVariable = SUBSTRING(@LastVariable, 4, 7)
                                        
            SET @TargetWidth = Cast(4 AS Int)
            SET @MaxTargetWidth = Cast(7 AS Int)
            SET @NewValue = ''
            SET @FinalValue = ''
            SET @ReplaceStringLength = Cast(0 AS Int)
            SET @ReplaceString = ''
            SET @NumberOfNine = 0
         
            IF (@AlphaNumericPartWidth = CAST(7 AS Int))
            BEGIN
                SET @PositionIndex = @AlphaNumericPartWidth
            
                WHILE(@PositionIndex > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @SelectedValue = SUBSTRING(@LastVariable, @PositionIndex, 1)
                    IF (@SelectedValue LIKE '[A-Z]') -- Increment alpha
                        SET @NewValue = dbo.IncrementAlphaValue(@SelectedValue)
                    ELSE -- Increment numeric
                        SET @NewValue = dbo.IncrementNumericValue(@SelectedValue)
                    -- Right most digit
                    IF (@PositionIndex = 1)
                    BEGIN
                        IF (@SelectedValue = 'Z')
                        BEGIN
                            -- If left of 'Z' all '9' replace with 'ZA'
                            IF (LEN(REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@LastVariable, 'Z', '.'), 1), '9','')) = 0)
                            BEGIN
                                SET @LastVariable = REPLACE(@LastVariable, 'Z', 'ZA');
                                SET @LastVariable = REPLACE(@LastVariable, '9', '0');
                                RETURN
                            END
                        END
                        -- If prefixed with letter or All '9', increment alpha
                        IF (@NewValue LIKE '[A-Y]' OR LEN(REPLACE(@LastVariable, '9','')) = 0)
                        BEGIN                           
                            SET @NewValue = dbo.IncrementAlphaValue(@SelectedValue)
                        END
                    END

                    SET @FinalValue = @NewValue + @FinalValue           

                    -- Break is it's 1
                    IF (@NewValue <> 9)
                        BREAK

                    -- Move position to left
                    SET @PositionIndex = @PositionIndex - Cast(1 As Int)
                END

                -- Check Final value length
                IF (LEN(@FinalValue) <= @MaxTargetWidth)
                BEGIN   
                    SET @LastVariable = @customerCode + @LastVariable
                    -- Get replace string length
                    SET @ReplaceStringLength = @PassParameterWidth -  Len(@FinalValue)
                    -- Get replace string
                    SET @ReplaceString = LEFT(@LastVariable, @ReplaceStringLength)

                    -- NEW CODE
                    SET @NewCODE = @ReplaceString + @FinalValue
            
                    SET @NewTarget = @NewCODE
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @NewTarget =  'ERROR1'
                END
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @NewTarget =  'ERROR222'
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: And what is wrong with a simple identity column?

Comment: Actually I'm working on a legacy code and the pattern is predefined.

Comment: Do you really have to worry about values going over 9,999,999?

Comment: similar questions asked a bazillion times previously on SO

Comment: Why is the next value to 999999 A00001 and not A00000?

Comment: strange requirement of ours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZZ99999';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABC0000001';
declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZZZZZZG';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABC9999999';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCA000001';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCE999999';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZ999999';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZG99999';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZA00001';
--declare @test varchar(10) = 'ABCZZ99999';

declare @idpart varchar(7) = SUBSTRING(@test, 4, 7);
declare @custpart varchar(7) = SUBSTRING(@test, 1, 3);

declare @numpos int = (SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @idpart));

declare @numpart varchar(7);
declare @letterpart varchar(7);

if @numpos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @numpart = SUBSTRING(@idpart, @numpos, 8 - @numpos);
        SET @letterpart = SUBSTRING(@idpart, 1, @numpos - 1);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @numpart = '';
        SET @letterpart = @idpart;
    END

declare @newnumpart varchar(7);
declare @newletterpart varchar(7);

IF @numpart = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @newletterpart = (SELECT REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE
                                    (REPLACE(@letterpart, 'Y', 'Z'), 
                                        'X', 'Y'), 
                                        'W', 'X'), 
                                        'V', 'W'), 
                                        'U', 'V'), 
                                        'T', 'U'), 
                                        'S', 'T'), 
                                        'R', 'S'), 
                                        'Q', 'R'), 
                                        'P', 'Q'), 
                                        'O', 'P'), 
                                        'N', 'O'), 
                                        'M', 'N'), 
                                        'L', 'M'), 
                                        'K', 'L'), 
                                        'J', 'K'), 
                                        'I', 'J'), 
                                        'H', 'I'), 
                                        'G', 'H'), 
                                        'F', 'G'), 
                                        'E', 'F'), 
                                        'D', 'E'), 
                                        'C', 'D'), 
                                        'B', 'C'), 
                                        'A', 'B'));
        SET @newnumpart = '';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        declare @non9 int = (SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-8]%', @numpart));

        IF @non9 > 0
            BEGIN
                --Number part is not all 9s so we can cast as int add 1 and cast back to varchar
                declare @numint int = (SELECT CAST(@numpart as int) + 1);
                declare @numstr varchar(7) = (SELECT CAST(@numint as varchar(7)));
                SET @newnumpart = (SELECT REPLICATE('0', LEN(@numpart) - LEN(@numstr)) + @numstr);
                SET @newletterpart = @letterpart;
            END
        ELSE
            IF @letterpart = ''
                BEGIN
                    SET @newnumpart = '000001';
                    SET @newletterpart = 'A';
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    declare @nonZ int = (SELECT PATINDEX('%[A-Y]%', @letterpart));
                    IF @nonZ > 0
                        BEGIN
                            SET @newletterpart = (SELECT REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE
                                                        (REPLACE(@letterpart, 'Y', 'Z'), 
                                                            'X', 'Y'), 
                                                            'W', 'X'), 
                                                            'V', 'W'), 
                                                            'U', 'V'), 
                                                            'T', 'U'), 
                                                            'S', 'T'), 
                                                            'R', 'S'), 
                                                            'Q', 'R'), 
                                                            'P', 'Q'), 
                                                            'O', 'P'), 
                                                            'N', 'O'), 
                                                            'M', 'N'), 
                                                            'L', 'M'), 
                                                            'K', 'L'), 
                                                            'J', 'K'), 
                                                            'I', 'J'), 
                                                            'H', 'I'), 
                                                            'G', 'H'), 
                                                            'F', 'G'), 
                                                            'E', 'F'), 
                                                            'D', 'E'), 
                                                            'C', 'D'), 
                                                            'B', 'C'), 
                                                            'A', 'B'));
                            SET @newnumpart = (SELECT REPLICATE('0', LEN(@numpart) - 1) + '1'); 
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @newletterpart = @letterpart + 'A';
                            SET @newnumpart = (SELECT REPLICATE('0', LEN(@numpart) - 2) + '1'); 
                        END
                END
    END

    SELECT @custpart + @newletterpart + @newnumpart;
```

Obviously I have only done it as a straight query, but it is trivial to generate a stored procedure from it.  The two key test cases are whether the number element is all 9s and the letter element is all Zs.  If the number element is not all 9s then we get the next number part by cast to int adding 1 and casting back to varchar using `REPLICATE` to pad zeros.  If the number element is all zeros, then the second key case comes in.  Do we have a letter that we can increment, or do we add an extra 'A' at the end, because we only have Zs.  The way I incremented the letters A-Y via multiple 'REPLACE' might be improved at least as far as elegance is concerned, but it is quick!

One thing puzzles me though.  If this is a legacy issue, how were the previous developers generating the next value.  Presumably they were doing so?

Comment: Thanks for the query! The old code adds the letter from right instead of left of the sequence.